# Can I wear this and pray and do other stuff

Tags: halal-haram, salat, clothing

Is it permissible to wear this hoodie[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

In terms of praying, the law is MAKRUH. Because the painting on the dress can disturb others like the picture on the back of the shirt, it will definitely disturb the person who is praying in the back.

Some scholars condemn it as HARAM. The Prophet S.A.W. curse those who paint pictures of creatures.

However, some scholars condemned it as MAKRUH. To avoid disturbing others in prayer, it is better if the shirt is turned over before prayer.

Despite that, your prayer remains valid.

Wallahualam.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is, No

Wearing a garment (cloth, hoodie etc..) with any image of a being with a soul is not permissible, but to remove such image (by painting, cutting, etc...) and then wear it, this is permissible.

And Allah knows best.